# tabhost - order of view children changed in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, tabwidget

I can't seem to fix what ought to be a simple problem with my TabHost layout. I construct the xml, as in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TabWidget>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/favouriteslist"
        style="@style/POITab_Lists">
        </ListView>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/recentlist"
        style="@style/POITab_Lists">
        </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and yet my FrameLayout appears **before** my TabWidget, crowding it out:[image]

This seems quite unusual to me - does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You mean it appears above in Hierarchy Viewer drawing? That seems quite a normal for me - this utility draws in this view XML tree hierarchy, not the layout itself.
If everything in the Graphical Layout is ok (TabWidget is above FrameLayout) then you have nothing to worry about :)

Comment: Yes, I should have been more explicit - the TabWidget doesn't draw at all with that layout and setting some of the other widgets to wrap_content merely draws the TabWidget under the FrameLayout - not the desired effect. This is confirmed by the screenshot above. BTW I'm not sure what you say is true about Hierarchy Viewer is true - what happens if a layout is created at Runtime - you can't run Hierarchy Viewer?